# Both parent process and child process stuck at opening named pipe

Tags: file-io, pipe, named-pipes, blocking

Parent process has successfully created named pipes for each helper process using
mkfifo(pipe_name, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR)

Then it launches helpers, and opens each pipe by:

```
::open(pipe_name, O_WRONLY);
```

On the helper process side, it opens the reader side of the pipe by:

```
::open(pipe_name, O_RDONLY);
```

And there are some reading and writing going on afterwards.

The program almost always works, expect in occasional cases, it stucks!
And when I attach the processes to ddd, I see that both the main and helper processes stuck at opening the pipe. 
I have been confused by this phenomenon by days and can't figure it out. Plus I've no idea how to debug this: how do I have the processes time out and return the error code?

Comment: BTW, the pipe names are generated using mkstemp and is prefixed with "/tmp/", so it will be for example: /tmp/dl_pipe0WSk9yP for one helper and /tmp/dl_pipe1VQY2Cs for the other. I don't see it as a problem though..

Comment: Why do you use 2 filenames? Do you need more than one pipe? Note: "opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also" There is no timeout.